# Java Chinese characters in button with verdana font

Tags: java, swing, unicode, fonts

I need to display Chinese characters in my application.
I use Verdana font.
Labels (`JLabel`) correctly display these characters using the font but the text button (`JButton`) displays squares instead of characters.

Any idea?

Comment: Verdana doesn't have any support for CJK. The system picks the glyph from another font – a mechanism that *should* be working regardless of the control you're using, though.

Comment: Verdana TTF font doesn't support Chinese characters! I suspect that OP has mistakenly assumed the font he sees working on the label is the Verdana font. I don't think so. It is likely the font he see is actually the default Java logical font, Dialog font. I believe he didn't set the label's `setFont()` properly with Verdana font. To confirm my suspicion, OP please type this `System.out.println(label.getFont());`

Comment: It is really strange since Verdana doesn't support [CJK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts). I had a unit test that confirms my suspicion in which Verdana produces rectangle boxes for CJK Unicode sequences...Can you provide the [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
jLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("MS Song", 0, 12));
```

Comment: This is very unlikely to be an encoding problem if their labels work ... for developers working with foreign languages the character set is usually rarely a problem as they simply *can't* accidentally assume all ASCII.

Comment: Actually, squares are really a font problem, and changing it to MS Song has big chances to succeed. There are too many things that might affect the result to tell why JButton does not work, and JLabel does. For instance calling the Win APIs with different flags for JButton. Or the fact the buttons use bold fonts. The Windows version, the Uniscribe version. Maybe the font is not really the same (mistakes happen). But squares (usually) means bad font. And explicitly selecting a Chinese font can eliminate the bad encoding suspicions. So this answer is a good step toward a solution.

Comment: Very helpful! Here a list of more supporting fonts http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts

Answer (score 2):

It might be the case that you need to enter the Chinese characters as unicode as shown in this example:

```
JLabel chineseJLabel = new JLabel("\u6B22\u8FCE\u4F7F\u7528" + "\u0020\u0020Unicode\u0021");
chineseJLabel.setToolTipText("This is Traditional Chinese");
```

Obtained from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UnicodewithLabel.htm). You can then use [Native2Ascii](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-chinese-character-to-unicode-with-native2ascii/) to convert your string into unicode.

Comment: and why does it work perfectly with label ? I use the same string.

Comment: This is very unlikely to be an encoding problem if their labels work ... for developers working with foreign languages the character set is usually rarely a problem as they simply *can't* accidentally assume all ASCII.